# SCSS: сделать код более компактным применив вложение для элементов с hover

Tags: css, css3, scss

у меня есть такой код scss:

```
/* кнопки-иконки */
button.btn-icon {
  box-shadow:           none;
  background:           none;

  border-radius:        50%;
}

button.btn-icon:not(:disabled) svg {
  background:           none;
  fill:                 $color_main_disactive;
}

button.btn-icon:disabled svg {
  background:           none;
  fill:                 $color_main_disabled;
}

button.btn-icon:not(:disabled):hover svg {
  fill:                 $color_main_active;
}
```

наверное по scssному стоит использовать вложенность для того же `svg`, но как это все хозяйство будет выглядеть с учетом всех этих псевдоклассов?

или такой код править - только портить (я в плане читабельности и более правильного подхода конкретно для scss)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да не сильно тут что-то сделаешь, по крайней мере, насколько я знаю. Для `svg` тут ничего нельзя сделать, каскадно же всё.

```
button.btn-icon {
  box-shadow: none;
  background:  none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  &:not(:disabled) {
    svg {
      background: none;
      fill: $color_main_disactive;
    }
    
    &:hover {
      svg {
        fill: $color_main_active;
      }
    }
  }
  
  &:disabled svg {
    background: none;
    fill: $color_main_disabled;
  }
}
```

Вкладывать в SCSS код всегда желательно, иначе смысла от SCSS мало, но и в этом случае оно сильно не помогает. Хотя читать вроде так немного легче.

Comment: да, я как раз про возможность более удобного чтения

Comment: а такой вопрос по теме - если у меня есть второй подобный класс, который отличается парой свойств -  почему мне не удается отнаследовать как `@extend button.btn-icon` - выдается ошибка?

Comment: @Zhihar Потому что ["Only simple selectors—individual selectors like"](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#disallowed-selectors), то есть надо отказаться от `button` и оставить только `.btn-icon`, тогда по идее заработает. Но я экстендами почти не пользовался, не было особо желания и задач)